# Safari's 'Shared Links' in Notification Center

Tags: safari, macos, notifications

Safari has the option to subscribe to RSS feeds, so you can watch them in the 'Shared Links' section of your browser. I'm wondering, is it possible to receive "push notifications" for this in the Notification Center?

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no way to do this at the moment.